# do-while loop skipping code

Tags: java, loops

I'm having trouble with this do-while loop here. It runs smoothly the first time but after it asks for a country the second time, it won't let me input. Any help?

```
import java.util.*;

public class UseList
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);        
    ListInterface<String> list = new ArraySortedList<String>();
    String country, flag;
    char flagCharred;

    do
    {            
        System.out.print("Enter a country you've visited: ");
        country = userInput.nextLine();
        list.add(country);

        System.out.print("\n" +list);

        System.out.print("\nAdd another country?: Y/N ");
        flag = userInput.next();
        flagCharred = flag.charAt(0);
    } 
while (flagCharred == 'y' || flagCharred == 'Y');
}
}
```

Comment: next() only reads a word, not the whole line.  Try using nextLine() instead as this appears to be what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

[`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) **doesn't** consume the end of line, so it'll be consumed in the next [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29).

For example, when you write `Y` as the second input, you are actually writing `Y` and pressing *enter*, which is the `'\n'` character, the `next` will read the `Y` and the `'\n'` will be the input for the `nextLine` causing it so skip the "real" input you wanted.

One solution is to change `next` to `nextLine`.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution for your problem

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UseList
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

String country, flag;

char flagCharred;

do
{            
    System.out.print("Enter a country you've visited: ");
    country = userInput.nextLine();
    list.add(country);

    System.out.print("\n" +list);

    System.out.print("\nAdd another country?: Y/N ");
    flag = userInput.next();
    flagCharred = flag.charAt(0);
    country = userInput.nextLine();

}
```

while ('y'==flagCharred || 'Y'==flagCharred);

}

}